# Autolayout in iPhone Portrait Mode

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have to design an app for all iPhone size portrait mode only. I am using storyboard and setting constraints using storyboard itself. What makes me confuse is `Size Classes`. Since my requirement is iPhone portrait only, I am using Size Class `compact Width|regular Height`. My question is can I disable the Size Classes cause working only for iPhone portrait mode. If yes, then can I design with Size Classes disabled for all iPhone size. What is the right approach?

Comment: Refer these links for more information on Layout and Size Classes.https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html. Hope it helps. For AutoLayout you can refer this too.http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: I have seen all the documentation and tutorial, but its all about showing how to make it working with 3-4 UIViews.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, prior to size classes, storyboard UI was designed by doing a separate interface for each iPhone size.  Since the advent of a broad range of device sizes, size classes have been incorporated.  Considering that your app may have to run on older devices, there is still a difference in size between iPhones in portrait mode.  Because of this, you would likely have to make a separate interface for each orientation, which I have not tried.  I believe the correct approach would be to simply design for the size class that you selected.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only making your application for iPhone portrait not necessary to use the size classes. You just have to set proper contract which are in the size indicator. 
It's my opinion for it. 
If you are developing for iPad and iPhone size class is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Size classes deal with the problem of multiple orientations(portrait and landscape) and different devices(iPhone and iPad). You cannot differentiate between two different screen sizes for iPhone using a size class. Similarly you cannot differentiate between iPad mini(portrait) and iPad Air(portrait) on behalf of size classes.

All iPhones in portrait has the same size class behavior i.e Compact(width) | Regular(height), be it 3.5", 4.0", 4.7" or 5.5". Similarly all iPhones in landscape has Regular(width) | Compact(height) size class. Size classes aren't the solution to the problem you are facing.

In order to handle multiple screen sizes for iPhone in portrait, the best bet would be to make use of autolayouts. Pin your views with the boundaries so that they will get stretched or contracted on different screens. Similarly bind your labels with the boundaries of their superview so that they will grow too. Also you can make use of aspect-ratio constraint that will allow to grow your view and images relative to the aspect-ratio of the element rather than increasing them horizontally to end up with an elongated look.

If you are new to autolayouts I will highly recommend watching the following sessions from WWDC2012:

1. [Introduction to Auto Layouts](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/202/)
2. [Auto Layouts by Example](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/232/)
3. [Best Practices for Mastering Auto Layouts](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/228/)